# Error: processing vignette 'QuickStart.Rmd' failed with diagnostics: there is no package called 'utf8'

Tags: r, package, devtools, cran

I am now updating the package version to 0.2.1 on CRAN.

After doing, devtools::check_rhub(), the error said:

```
checking re-building of vignette outputs (1.9s)
   Error(s) in re-building vignettes:
     ...
   --- re-building 'QuickStart.Rmd' using rmarkdown
   Quitting from lines 74-75 (QuickStart.Rmd) 
   Error: processing vignette 'QuickStart.Rmd' failed with diagnostics:
   there is no package called 'utf8'
   --- failed re-building 'QuickStart.Rmd'
   
   SUMMARY: processing the following file failed:
     'QuickStart.Rmd'
   
   Error: Vignette re-building failed.
   Execution halted
```

And I checked the code from lines 74-75 is

```
generate_ts(n.ts = 3, freq = 12, nComp = 2, n = 120, output_format = "tsibble")
```

[image]

I tried to add `library(utf8)` in **vignette**  then I get an error from `devtools::check(cran=TRUE)` said:

```
checking for unstated dependencies in vignettes ... NOTE
  'library' or 'require' call not declared from: 'utf8'
```

I tried to add both `library(utf8)` in **vignette** and `utf8` in **DESCRIPTION**, but this further led an error

```
checking package dependencies ... ERROR
  
  The suggested packages are required for a complete check.
  Checking can be attempted without them by setting the environment
  variable _R_CHECK_FORCE_SUGGESTS_ to a false value.
  
  See section 'The DESCRIPTION file' in the 'Writing R Extensions'
  manual.
```

Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Other codes in vignette

```
title: "Introduction to gratis"
author: "Bocong Zhao"
output: rmarkdown::html_vignette
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Introduction to gratis}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}

{r initial, echo = FALSE, cache = FALSE, results = 'hide'}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(
  warning = FALSE, message = FALSE, echo = TRUE,
  fig.width = 7, fig.height = 6, fig.align = 'centre',
  comment = "#>"
)

{r, message=FALSE, include = FALSE}
library(forecast)
library(tsibble)
library(utf8)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reference answer from this website,

github.com/r-hub/rhub/issues/374

Runing this code would fix the issue `devtools::check_rhub(env_vars=c(R_COMPILE_AND_INSTALL_PACKAGES = "always"))`